# NoMethodError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new

Tags: activeadmin, nomethoderror

I have looked through numerous articles now where a number of them touch on this but none seem to resolve the issue I'm having. I have installed ActiveAdmin and everything was working fine until I tried pushing to heroku.  Now I'm getting the below error and not sure how to resolve.

```
NoMethodError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new

Showing /Users/gregoryhooven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bundler/gems/active_admin-6c9e22ab0922/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

xtracted source (around line #7):

<% scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_name) %>
<%= active_admin_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => send(:"# {scope}_session_path"), :html => { :id => "session_new" }) do |f|
f.inputs do
**resource.class.authentication_keys.each { |key| f.input key, :input_html => {:autofocus => true}}**
f.input :password
f.input :remember_me, :label => t('active_admin.devise.login.remember_me'), :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but maybe to use for others. 
I  kind of had the same issue on my local system. I wanted to reinstall activeadmin. After reinstall  webrick gave me this error code if is tried `127.0.0.1:3000/admin/login`

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `new_password_path' for#<#<Class:0x007fc7ef1a3d08>:0x007fc7ef1a2f70>):
```

and also the rendered view looked not very nicely. I figured out i had to  some gem dependencies not met. Via `bundle install` i updated `sass` -from 3.4.16 to 3.4.14 - and  `arel`- from 6.0.0 to 6.0.2.  Then it worked nicely. Strange is that before i reinstalled activeadmin `rails g active_admin:install`  i updated all gems. And as far as i understand activeadmin installs its needed packages and i did not touch my `Gemfile` for a while.